# python selenium firefox behavior

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I am using a firefox browser with selenium. I am scraping a website that has multiple pages like google search, where you can pick the page at the bottom. On each page, I click an element, like google again, and scrap data from that element's information. If I am at an element's information on the third page, and click the back button using my regular firefox browser, it goes back to the third page. But, when I press the back button in selenium with driver.back(), it takes me back to the first page. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
count = 1
while 1:
    try:
        pages = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.page-number.gradient")
    except:
        break
    for page in pages:
        if page.text==str(count):
            page.click()
            print count
            break
    states = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='table_div']/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[19]")
    fails = []
    i = 1
    for state in states:
        if state.text == "FAILED":
            fails.append(i)
        i+=1

    for fail in fails:
        print driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='table_div']/div/div/table/tbody/tr[" + str(fail) + "]/td[19]").text
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='table_div']/div/div/table/tbody/tr[" + str(fail) + "]/td[1]/input").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        errors = driver.find_element_by_name("errors")
        if "\n" in errors.text:
            fixedText = errors.text.split("\n")[0]
            errors.clear()
            errors.send_keys(fixedText)
            time.sleep(1)
            driver.find_element_by_name('post_type').click()
            time.sleep(5)
            driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
            driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
            driver.back()
            driver.back()
        else:
            driver.back()
            driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
            driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
    count+=1
```

The code is really complicated, but basically it's the driver.back() lines that aren't working

Comment: Can you please post the code you are using as well?

Comment: i just added the code